# How did the Doctor remember the ship name?

Tags: doctor-who

In ***Deep Breath*** (series 8) the Doctor tries to remember a previous incident with

> clockwork androids stealing human body parts to repair machinery.

Yet he can't. During another conversation with the episode's main "villain", he finally remembers a few parts of his own history.

He's looking at the backside of some kind of fuse and reads the name

> SS Marie Antoinette

and shortly later combines this with the name of the supposed sister ship:

> SS Madame de Pompadour

The actual event he remembers has been depicted in an episode of series 1 (2005).

> However, as far as I remember, at the end of *The Girl in the Fireplace* the Doctor just kept wondering why the droids wanted *Madame de Pompadour* specifically. As far as I know it's only shown to the audience that the ship's hull has *Madame de Pompadour* written on its flank, essentially revealing its name.

So did I just miss the Doctor noticing the name? Or is this a plot hole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He didn't see the name of the ship before they left the SS Pompadour and it's not apparent from the [script of Deep Breath](https://pdf.yt/d/wTb7a_AmAvb8vCwX/download) that he's definitively linked the two ships together. He's merely reading the data-chip.

Obviously *we know* that they're linked (that's the joke), but there's no indication to suggest that he knows:

> **THE DOCTOR :** *SS Marie Antoinette. Out of control repair Droids, cannibalizing human beings. I know this is familiar, but I just can’t
>   seem to place it.*
>
> The Half-Face Man responds -
>
> **HALF-FACE MAN :** *How would you kill me?*
>
> **THE DOCTOR :** *Sister Ship of ...* (Squints closer, writing is a bit faded) *...the Madame De Pompadour.*
>
> (Considers, reflects)
>
> **THE DOCTOR :** **Nope, not getting it.**

Obviously he's noticed the similarity in the design of the robots as well as the situation though but his swiss-cheesed memory is playing tricks on him.

Comment: Ah okay, that sounds more reasonable. Didn't try to interpret it that way.

Comment: It's probably because it's been centuries (well over a 1000 years in fact, when you consider how long the 11th Doctor lived), so it's only natural that he'd forget. It's the same with anyone after a long time.